# Android studio - emulator is not working properly

Tags: android-studio, ubuntu, android-emulator

i am using Android studio 2.2.3 i installed ide and tools  .  I am currently using ubuntu 16.04   64 bit operating system . My VT-x is enabled in my BIOS and i installed kvm using this link  https://github.com/uw-it-aca/spacescout-android/wiki/1.-Setting-Up-Android-Studio-on-Ubuntu  . I am trying to create the virtual device but its not showing in the AVD-manager giving the blank window only .

[image showing the blank window of the avd manger after creating the virtual device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KLtjW.png)

i searched the net and find that emulator tab is missing maybe i don't know .

i am new to android studio and Ubuntu please tell in detail, i checked the target-api also and set in the Build-gradle file .